# undefined variable: id while clicking a dynamic image in homepage using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

`Controller:`

```
public function latestnews()
{   
    $data['news'] = $this->New_model->getById($id);
    $this->load->view('news',$data);
}
```

`Model:`

```
public function getById($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["new_id" => $id])->row();
}
```

`View:`

```
       <?php 
       if (isset($news) and $news) {
          foreach($news as $new) {
           ?>    

           <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="section">
                  <img  src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$new->image); ?>" />
                 </div>
                 <p><?php echo $new->description;?> </p>
            </div>

          <?php           
           }
          }
         ?>
```

How and where to define the variable id?

While clicking a dynamic image,it should be opened in another page containing details but instead showing Undefined variable: id

Answer (score 0):

In the `latestnews()` function you have no `$id` defined.

Try to call the `latestnews()` function with the right `$id` parameter.

Comment: how to define id in latestnews() ?

Comment: Try to pass it as a parameter from where you call it. 
`public function latestnews($id)
 {   
    $data['news'] = $this->New_model->getById($id);
    $this->load->view('news',$data);
 }`

Comment: 2 errors..Missing argument 1 for Index::latestnews() and Undefined variable: id

Comment: Where do you call ```latestnews()```?

Answer (score 0):

you can write function like this,

```
function latestnews($id)
{
```

Comment: 2 errors..Missing argument 1 for Index::latestnews() and Undefined variable: id

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
   function single_news($id) { // This $id variable comes from URL Ex: example.com/single_news/15. So $id = 15
      $this->data['news_data'] = $this->new_model->getNewsByID($id);
      $this->load->view('single-news', $this->data); // Create New View file named single-news.php
   }
```

**Model:**

```
function getNewsByID($id) {
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $q = $this->db->get('news');
   if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $q->row();
   }
  return false;
}
```

**View: (Single News Page)**

```
<div>
  <img src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$news_data->image); ?>" />
</div>
```